# Need to add an element in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need to add an element to the numpy array. But append and extend are both not working. 
Here a1 is a function.

```
import numpy as np
def a1(f):
    return 700*(np.exp(f/1125.0) - 1)

f = np.zeros(26)
N = 26
f_min = 300
f_max = 16000

for n in range(N):
    f[n] = (f_min + n*(f_max - f_min)/(N-1))

h = a1(f)
h = h[::-1]
np.append(h, 0)
print h
```

The output is:

```
[ 16000.          14221.33951611  12632.11814102  11212.15935635
  9943.43557641   8809.83927267   7796.97847492   6891.99405301
  6083.39645924   5360.91985872   4715.39179592   4138.6167425
  3623.27204809   3162.81497306   2751.39962281   2383.80272921
  2055.35733672   1761.89355146   1499.68560083   1265.40453166
  1056.07594631    869.04224018    701.92886113    552.61416253
  419.20246718    300.        ]
```

Why is the 0 in the last is not getting appended? Also the type of h is numpy.ndarray.

Comment: Instead of that `for-loop` (and `np.zeros`), you could use `f = np.linspace(f_min, f_max, N)`.

Comment: I'll implement that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign `np.append(h, 0)` to `h` like

```
h = np.append(h, 0)
print h
```